# Apache2 calibration check

Tags: apache-2.2

I research a lot in google for a script that tell me if apache2 is configurated well and it's capabilites/calibration are set correctly.

I use `mpm_prefork_module` and I would to know if params are set correctly for my machine.

This is my actual params:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers       25
    MaxClients            50
    MaxRequestsPerChild   500
    ServerLimit           50
</IfModule>
```

The question is very simple, anyone know a script (bash prefered) that check apache2 calibration?

Answer (score 0):

The correct performance tuning is highly dependent on your specific workload. You will need to run a benchmark to tell. Several http benchmark programs are out there including Apache's own ab.

If a benchmark is difficult, consider carefully adding the change in production. One server at a time behind a load balancer if possible, so you can see the difference and back out if necessary.

During the test watch the number of server processes and threads, as well as operating system performance metrics. apachectl status  can show the threads, and some log file parsing can show request rates.

If all you want is a syntax check, you can get that with apachectl configtest.